# How to display a self-refreshing "popout" html GET page in a fanciful AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

I've got a web form done many donkey years ago that generates on form submit a popout html- page that refreshes itself every 10 seconds with the latest data drawn from the database.

Many browsers now prevent popouts, so I reckon that I need to rework the same web form to generate an AJAX or AJAX like "popout" that is not affected by browser security settings that block popout by default?  Please advise if otherwise.

The "popout" should be movable, auto-refreshing and include a close button.  I would also need to link to the "popout" from a html link.

Would like to hear from you web experts what are my options?  :)

Comment: have you looked at jQueryUI? it does nice and fancy dialogs - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Agree on jQuery UI; combine it with Ajax-get to refresh every ten seconds and you're done!

Comment: here is a good site with many modal/dialog box  if you need one without jQuery or using another library http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation as I said in my comment would be to take a look at jQueryUI specifically around the dialog (example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

You could then use a javascript timer to periodically poll your server using jQuery Ajax (which if you haven't looked at before I would highly recommend) - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/